# Capture span value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Everyone I want to capture price from this span using jquery how can i achieve this please suggest something

```
<span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1,000</span>
```

DropDown:

```
<li class="tmcp-field-wrap">
<label for="tmcp_select_1">Select</label>
            <select class="tmcp-field support-layer-firmness tm-epo-field tmcp-select tm-valid" name="tmcp_select_0">
               <option value="Select Firmness_0" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="">Select Firmness</option>
               <option value="Soft_1" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1000">Soft</option>
               <option value="Medium_2" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option" data-price="1500">Medium</option>
               <option value="Hard_3" class="tc-multiple-option tc-select-option"  data-price="2000">Hard</option>  
             </select>
<span class="price tc-price  hidden">
     <span class="amount"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i>1,000</span>
</span>
```

Now i want to get value using onchange event

**I have tried so far**

```
$(".support-layer-firmness .tc-price span").on("change", function() {

  var price =  $('span.amount').text();
  alert(price);
});
```

Comment: ___`$('.amount').text()`___

Comment: `$('span.amount').text()`

Comment: Thank you ....please no downvotes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the text by using jquery [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('span.amount').text(); // output 1,000
```

> Class Selector: Selects all elements with the given class. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

As per comment if you want to get the same span value onChange event then try this.

**Method 1**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('span.amount').text();
});
```

**Method 2**

You can use also class for selecting the `select` element

```
$('select.tmcp-field').on('change', function() {
   $('span.amount').text();
});
```

Comment: ok it's working fine but how can i select span value using onchange event

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6971/)

You can easily get span value as follow.

On Change you can do something like this

```
$('.tmcp-select').on('change', function (e) {
      alert($('span.amount').text());
  });
```

**OnChange** [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6973/)

Answer (score 1):

use jquery [selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) using class name

```
$(".amount").text();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mc7h22f7/

Comment: it's working fine but how can i select span value using onchange event

Comment: i am trying like this $(".support-layer-firmness .tc-price span").on("change", function() {
  var price =  $('span.amount').text();
  alert(price);
});

Comment: You have to change the span text when dropdown select is triggeres, after that only your code run.